# Lipschitz continuity implies differentiability almost everywhere.

Tags: derivatives, lipschitz-functions, almost-everywhere

I am running into some troubles with Lipschitz continuous functions.

Suppose I have some one-dimensional Lipschitz continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. How do I prove that its derivative exists almost everywhere, with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

I found on other places on the internet that any Lipschitz continuous function is absolutely continuous, and that this directly implies that the functions is differentiable almost everywhere. I don't quite see how this argument goes, though.

Any help with giving such a proof, or redirecting me to a source where I can find one, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the reasoning using absolute continuity do you not get? The fact that Lipshitz implies AC, or  the fact that AC implies differentiability ae? (Or both?)

Comment: The part that AC implies differentiability ae. :)

Comment: This is known as [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An excellent reference for the properties of Lipschitz functions is *[Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf)* by Juha Heinonen. The differentiability a.e. is Theorem 3.2, page 19. I state the steps of the proof here:

1. Lipschitz continuity implies having bounded variation.
2. A function of bounded variation can be written as the difference of two increasing functions
3. An increasing function is differentiable almost everywhere: this is the main step of the proof, which uses the [Vitali covering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Vitali.27s_covering_theorem_for_the_Lebesgue_measure). Concerning this step, see also [$f$ continuous, monotone, what do we know about differentiability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/713033)

Comment: Wow, this turned out to be somewhat harder than I expected. Thanks for the references!

Comment: What if $f:R^n \to R$?

Comment: @Ashkan Theorem 3.1 in Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis that are linked in the post.

Comment: Hi, concerning the part where the vitali covering is used. The part $q|E_q| \leq |f(E_q)|$ is not so clear to me. Do you maybe understand how the author came to this conclusion? @user357151