# lipschitz function in a compact, is it differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a lipschitz function in $[0,1]$,

(it exists a $C>0$ that we have for all $x,y \in [0,1]$ $|f(x)-f(y)|<C.|x-y|$)

Can we prove that $f$ is differentiable ?

Comment: Nope. A counterexample is $f(x)= |x|$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem for a similar result.

Comment: @Crostul yeh you re right, thank you

Comment: @Crostul minor correction: $|x|$ is differentiable on $[0,1].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, try $f(x) = |x - 1/2|$.

Comment: Oh, yeh thats right,

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. The function $x \mapsto |x|$ gives a counterexample.

However, Lipschitz functions are differentiable almost everywhere:

[Lipschitz continuity implies differentiability almost everywhere.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101956/lipschitz-continuity-implies-differentiability-almost-everywhere)

Also note that if the derivative is bounded, the converse is true.