# How does function $x_i \rightarrow f(x_1,x_2, ..., x_i, ..., x_n)$ Lipschitz imply existence of partial derivatives?

Tags: partial-derivative

How does function $x_i \rightarrow f(x_1,x_2, ..., x_i, ..., x_n)$ Lipschitz imply existence of partial derivatives?

Particularly, is there a way to write this in such form that expresses component-wise differentiability?

Comment: Lipschitz functions are not necessarily everywhere differentiable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Examples

Comment: @edm But actually in my case "almost everywhere differentiable" suffices.

Answer (score 0):

This question will help you: [Lipschitz continuity implies differentiability almost everywhere.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101956/lipschitz-continuity-implies-differentiability-almost-everywhere) This problem is a little bit hard to solve, but there is a reference in this question with the prove.

Comment: I was reading that paper, it doesn't explain it fully. Only in broad strokes.